# Add user to a group in Active Directory using powershell

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am trying to add a user to a group in AD using powershell. I am using the following command:

```
Add-ADGroupMember 
-Identity "CN=yasar-test,OU=AFS-OU-ACLs-EDMS,OU=AFS-OU-Groups,OU=AFS,OU=FA,OU=DEPARTMENTS,DC=ou,DC=ad3,DC=ucdavis,DC=edu"
-Members ("CN=xyz,OU=ucdUsers,DC=ad3,DC=ucdavis,DC=edu") 
-Server "ou.ad3.ucdavis.edu" -Credential  -authtype 0
```

I keep getting an error:

```
Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'CN=xyz,OU=ucdUsers,DC=ad3,DC=ucdavis,DC=edu' under: 'DC=o
u,DC=ad3,DC=ucdavis,DC=edu'.
At line:1 char:18
```

However, when I look for XYZ in AD I can find them.  Any clue what's going on?

Comment: What is your AD's DNS name? ou.ad3.ucdavis.edu or just ad3.ucdavis.edu? In the identity switch you're referencing the former. In the members switch, you're using the latter.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the parenthesis around the member.  Try:

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "CN=yasar-test,OU=AFS-OU-ACLs-EDMS,OU=AFS-OU-Groups,OU=AFS,OU=FA,OU=DEPARTMENTS,DC=ou,DC=ad3,DC=ucdavis,DC=edu" -Members "CN=xyz,OU=ucdUsers,DC=ad3,DC=ucdavis,DC=edu" -Server "ou.ad3.ucdavis.edu" -Credential -authtype 0
```

Actually, it works either way, you may not have a valid DN there.  Try using their SAMAccount name instead.

Answer (score 2):

Double check DNs you provided in the command line. Assuming the statements we read was exactly what you used, the group belongs to a domain called "ou.ad3.ucdavis.edu", while the user belongs to "ad3.ucdavis.edu". Not that you can't add foreign user into your group (as long as it's domain local), but it looks more like you had a typo.

Read the user into a variable, and then use the variable in add-ADgroupMember is sure way to check if you have correct DN for user.

$user=get-ADuser xxxx
add-adGroupMember -members $user ....